# Calling a function dynamically based on an integer value

Tags: c#

I want to call a different function without write `if` conditions like this:

```
if(a==1)
{
    function1 ();
}
if(a==2)
{
    function2 ();
}
if(a==3)
{
    function3 ();
}
```

I want to call function like this :

```
Dictionary<int, function> functions= new Dictionary<int, function>();
functions.add(1, function1);functions.add(2, function2);functions.add(3, function3);

function[1];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Replace `function` with `Func<...>`/`Action<...>`.

Comment: Have you heard about delegates ? Change your function what says @Sinatr and invoke like this function[1]()

Comment: Also read about delegates before you read about Func<> and Action<>,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<int, Func<bool>> funcMap = new Dictionary<int, Func<bool>>() {
        {1, Function1},
        {2, Function2}
    };


    Console.WriteLine(funcMap[1]());
    Console.WriteLine(funcMap[2]());
}

// Define other methods and classes here


bool Function1()
{
    return true;
}

bool Function2()
{
    return false;
}
```

This works because all functions have the same signature.

Comment: thank you for the answer.
but I can I have it with different signature

Comment: Possibly you need to explain how your code is getting used. You didn't gave us much to work with.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your functions are actually actions, since a function returns a value. Also you don't have any method parameters, so you have to use `Action`.

```
Dictionary<int, Action> functions= new Dictionary<int, Action>();
functions.Add(1, function1);
functions.Add(2, function2);
functions.Add(3, function3);

function[1](); // <-- calling here needs parentheses
```

Comment: No, unless you wrap that call in an action too (if possible). It is all the same or not.

Comment: there is no another issue??

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambdas to map functions with different signatures. Idea is the same as with `Action`:

```
var functions = new Dictionary<int, Action>
{
    { 1, () => method1(123) },
    { 2, () => method2(123, "123") },
};

functions[1](); // will call method1(123);
```

where functions are defined like this

```
void method1(int a) => Console.WriteLine(a);
void method2(int a, string b) => Console.WriteLine(a + b);
```